# Django ModuleNotFoundError. Everything is fine, but i am unable to run a server

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have started going through "Django for Beginners" book and copied code example from 2nd chapter, but it doesnt work because of the ModuleNotFoundError

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.apps.PagesConfigdjango'; 'pages.apps' is not a package
```

My app urls seem to be fine

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', homePageView, name = 'home')
]
```

As well as INSTALLED_APPS

```
'pages.apps.PagesConfig'
```

What is the possible problem?

Comment: you are missing comma after 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',

Comment: thank you, I literally spent an hour trying to figure out the issue